# How to unite gameobject meshes?

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, unityscript, mesh

Because of I made my house from the unity editor I can't remove this mesh borders. I tried MeshCombiner but it just connects all of the meshes in one mesh borders still exist. I know I can make it from Blender or something like this but is there any one to remove from unity?

Screen Shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbWJN.jpg

Comment: It looks like you need to re-map the texture to the new mesh (new uv's).

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the internal faces where the meshes overlap?  If so I would try using a CSG library from the asset store.  The CSG boolean Add operation removes internal faces.

Something like [SabreCSG](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/47418) might be exactly what you need:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [**CombineMeshes**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html). An example is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < meshFilters.Length) {
            combine[i].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
            combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            meshFilters[i].gameObject.active = false;
            i++;
        }
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = new Mesh();
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
        transform.gameObject.active = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being really late. Your answer also works but I resolved the problem with another kind of solution (I basically changed the idea that caused me to unite meshes.)